# For loop issue writing multiple lines to database

Tags: python, django

The for loop below has an issue when writing to the database.  Only the first record is coming through, i believe it's because report_name_sc = reportlist is writing the query set to the database.   How can I get it to write a single line for each report_id?

```
checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')
reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= checkedlist, active = 1).values_list('report_name_sc',flat = True)

for i in checkedlist:
    requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname_id = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                  ,report_id = i, report_name_sc = reportlist, accesslevel_id = '7', phi = '1', access_beg_date = '2017-01-01', access_end_date = '2017-01-31')
    requestsave.save()
```

Models.py added as requested, checked list is a collection of check boxes getting report_id:

```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin)
    from django.db import models
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.forms import ModelForm


    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):



        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
        formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_cfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        officename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        positioncode = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
        streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)



        USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

        class Meta:
            app_label = 'accounts'
            db_table = "user"

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
                domain='HCA', username=self.username)
            super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

        def get_short_name(self):
            return self.username




    #    REQUIRED_FIELDS = "username"

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s - %s %s' % (self.username, self.first_name, self.last_name)




    class FacilityDimension(models.Model):
        unit_num = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_Num', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        company_code = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        coid = models.CharField(db_column='Coid',primary_key=True, serialize=False, max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.
        coid_name = models.CharField(db_column='COID_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        c_level = models.CharField(db_column='C_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        company_name = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        s_level = models.CharField(db_column='S_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        sector_name = models.CharField(db_column='Sector_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        b_level = models.CharField(db_column='B_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        group_name = models.CharField(db_column='Group_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        r_level = models.CharField(db_column='R_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        division_name = models.CharField(db_column='Division_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        d_level = models.CharField(db_column='D_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        market_name = models.CharField(db_column='Market_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        f_level = models.CharField(db_column='F_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        cons_facility_name = models.CharField(db_column='Cons_Facility_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        lob_code = models.CharField(db_column='LOB_Code', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        lob_name = models.CharField(db_column='LOB_Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        sub_lob_code = models.CharField(db_column='Sub_LOB_Code', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        sub_lob_name = models.CharField(db_column='Sub_LOB_Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        state_code = models.CharField(db_column='State_Code', max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        pas_id_current = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_ID_Current', max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        pas_current_name = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Current_Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        pas_id_future = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_ID_Future', max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        pas_future_name = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Future_Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_7_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_7_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_8_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_8_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_phys_svc_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Phys_Svc_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_asd_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_ASD_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_imaging_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Imaging_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_oncology_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Oncology_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_cath_lab_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Cath_Lab_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_intl_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Intl_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        summary_other_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Other_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        pas_coid = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_COID', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        pas_status = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Status', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        company_code_operations = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code_Operations', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        osg_pas_ind = models.CharField(db_column='OSG_PAS_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        abs_facility_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='ABS_Facility_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        abl_facility_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='ABL_Facility_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        intl_pmis_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='INTL_PMIS_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        hsc_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='HSC_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        loaddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='LoadDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'Facility_Dimension'

    class QvDatareducecfo(models.Model):
        cfo_fname = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_FName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        cfo_lname = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_LName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        cfo_ntname = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,db_column='CFO_NTName',max_length=11, primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        cfo_type = models.IntegerField(db_column='CFO_Type', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        org_level_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Org_Level_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        org_level = models.CharField(db_column='Org_Level', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        unit_no = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_No', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        dr_code = models.CharField(db_column='DR_Code', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        dr_name = models.CharField(db_column='DR_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        cfo_dr_code = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_DR_Code', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        cfo_dr_name = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_DR_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        b_level = models.CharField(db_column='B_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        group_name = models.CharField(db_column='Group_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'QV_DataReduceCFO'

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.cfo_ntname)





    class QvReportList(models.Model):
        qv_dept_id = models.CharField(db_column='QV_Dept_ID', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_id = models.CharField(db_column='Report_ID',primary_key=True, max_length=100, serialize=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_name = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_name_sc = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name_SC', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        qv_filename = models.CharField(db_column='QV_FileName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_access = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Access', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_sub_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Sub_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        approver_fname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_FName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        approver_lname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_LName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        approver_ntname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_NTName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        approval_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Approval_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        role_based_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Role_Based_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'QV_Report_List'


    class QVReportAccess(models.Model):
        user_status = models.CharField(db_column='User_Status', max_length = 20)  # Field name made lowercase.
        ntname = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,db_column='NTName', max_length=11,primary_key=True, serialize=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_name = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_name_sc = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name_SC', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        datareduce_report_code = models.IntegerField(db_column='DataReduce_Report_Code', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        role_based_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Role_Based_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_id = models.OneToOneField(QvReportList,db_column='Report_ID', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_access = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Access', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        sr_datareduce_summary_code = models.CharField(db_column='SR_DataReduce_Summary_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        sr_datareduce_patient_code = models.CharField(db_column='SR_DataReduce_Patient_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        userid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        user_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='User_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)
        access_level_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Access_Level_ID', blank=True, null=True)
        active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)
        qv_statusid = models.IntegerField(db_column='QV_StatusID', blank=True, null=True)
        employee_status_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Employee_Status_ID', blank = True, null = True)
        new_user = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_User', blank = True, null = True)
        new_access = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_Access', blank = True, null = True)
        new_report = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_Report', blank = True, null = True)
        changed_row = models.IntegerField(db_column='Changed_Row',blank = True, null = True)
        last_change_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Last_Change_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        access_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Access_Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        access_end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Access_End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Report_Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        report_end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Report_End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        qv_startdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='QV_StartDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'QV_ReportAccess'

class QVFormAccessRequest(models.Model):
    ntname = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    report_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    report_name_sc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    accesslevel_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phi = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    access_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'QV_FormAccessRequest'






    class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
        app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        applied = models.DateTimeField()

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'django_migrations'

    class Sysdiagrams(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        principal_id = models.IntegerField()
        diagram_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        version = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        definition = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'sysdiagrams'
            unique_together = (('principal_id', 'name'),)
```

Comment: `reportlist` is a `QuerySet` in your example, you will not be able to assign it to a field on your `QVFormAccessRequest` model. Can you paste your models?

Comment: How can i convert my queryset into something that will return report_name_sc from the checkedlist?  Displaying the reportlist in my template using a for loop works, but in the for loop on the save it won't.  I'll paste my models tomorrow once i can get on my schools network.

Comment: added models as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `QVFormAccessRequest` model specifies `ntname` to be a primary key. So, there cannot be to model instances with the same primary key.

In your loop, you are iterating over `checkedlist`, but you always set the same `ntname_id`, so you are overwriting the previous object.

I suspect that you need to change your model to support what you want to achieve. Maybe, it is enough to remove the primary key constraint from `ntname` and let Django create a surrogate key (artificial key) for you.

Comment: I updated my models to remove the primary key constraint, but the report_name_sc is still publishing the entire query set for each row.

Comment: @student101: What do you mean by "is still publishing the entire query set for each row"? It would probably be easier if you, for the purpose of this question, reduce your model as far as possible such that the problem is still reproducible. Also, it might be helpful if you give examples for actual and expected results.

Comment: When I select multiple values, it does write to the database correctly for all other than report_name_sc.  It's writing as queryset[reportname1, reportname2, reportname3] for each row in the database under each report_id if i selected 3 report_id's.

Comment: @student101: What do you want it to write?

Comment: just the value of the report_name_sc for each report_id, not all three report_name_sc for each report_id.